# Call function only once after page load completely

Tags: jquery, function, settimeout

I want to call function one second after the page is completely loaded

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
  window.setInterval(function(){ your_func(); }, 1000);
});
```

It calls every second. I want it to be executed only once

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$(document).ready();`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() { your_func(); }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: This will call only once when page load complete @KetanKpBorada

Comment: Can you add "your_func();" In your question so i can help you better.  @KetanKpBorada

Answer (score 2):

You may use [$( document ).ready();](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) for that problem:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() { console.log( "ready!" ); }, 1000);

});
```

Comment: How your answer is different from @Bhavin answer which is already posted.

Comment: Yeah oddly identical to Bhavin Solanki's answer

Comment: @Yan, can you tell, how to debug the js, jquery in F12 in IE, or chrome browser. am unable to debug properly, dont know how to use console.log, and the sequence of steps.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution works well, don't need to change to document ready

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(window).bind("load", function() {
        setTimeout(function() { 
            console.log('Hey');
     }, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

Notice the differences between the events:

The **ready** event occurs after the HTML document has been loaded, while the **onload** event occurs later, when all content (e.g. images) also has been loaded.

Comment: You can see in the console that 'Hey' is only printed once @KetanKpBorada